# Как убрать межстрочный интервал в Xaml верстке?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

```
<Grid  Padding="20, 0, 0, 0" WidthRequest="400">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Ваше имя:"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   Padding="0"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                   FontSize="16"/>

            <Label Text="Средний балл:"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"

                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Avgscore, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                   FontSize="16"/>
            
            <Label Text="Здоровье:"
                   TextColor="#006EFF"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Health, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                   FontSize="16"/>
            
            <Label Text="Сытость:"
                   TextColor="#CF7A00"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Satiety, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                   FontSize="16"/>

            <Label Text="Сила"
                   TextColor="#F00009"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Power, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
                   FontSize="16"/>
            
            <Label Text="Деньги:"
                   FontSize="16"
                   TextColor="Green"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Money, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"
                   FontSize="16"/>

            <Label Text="Репутация:"
                   FontSize="16"
                   TextColor="#FF8200"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Reputation, FallbackValue=Pupil, TargetNullValue=Null}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"
                   FontSize="16"/>

        </Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О каком интервале речь?

Comment: Ну что бы Ваше имя и Средний бал и т.д. были ближе друг к другу.

Comment: Ну так у вас все в сетке, которая равномерно растягивает все колонки и строки на всю ее длину/ширину. Делайте значит сетку меньше по размерам, будут меньше расстояния. Ну либо позиционируйте сетку не на всю пространство, отведенное ей, а например, чтоб она была сверху.